# R package kernlab probabilities seem not to match decision

Tags: r, probability, classification, svm

For a classification problem I am giving the R package kernlab a shot – not the least because it offers to calculate class probabilities instead of only a plain decision. However, comparing results for both options appears to be contradictory. Some code for a 4 elemented testing data set:

```
model <- ksvm(x=formula,data=data[trainIndex,],
  prob.model=TRUE, type="C-svc");
predProb <- predict(model,data[testIndex,],type="probabilities");
predClass <- predict(model,data[testIndex,]);
```

In my 4 class case this led to:

```
> predProb
    desmino   filamino  myotilino     titino
[1,] 0.06676130 0.03833511 0.08397281 0.81093078
[2,] 0.06832143 0.83437244 0.03403721 0.06326892
[3,] 0.03655672 0.02404717 0.05114122 0.88825489
[4,] 0.03305530 0.05722160 0.68772201 0.22200108
> predClass
[1] myotilino filamino  titino    myotilino
Levels: desmino filamino myotilino titino
```

I am disturbed by the first line in the matrix. Clearly the probability attached to `titino` accounts for for the highest value. Still `myotilino` won in terms of predicted class. Is this a bug, or is there something I did not understand?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This of course is only an example where I omitted the data (it is a large 38x664 object). For completenesses sake: The true value would be 'titino'.

Comment: From another source it has been suggested, that the dataset may be too small (which in my humble opinion still would not warrant a contradiction in results). So here goes some more information: The training set contains 34 data points, the testing set the 4 points used in the example. For the 663 possible predictors it is guaranteed, that each column has 80% values >0 which are spectral counts from a proteomics experiment. Using either the svms from e1071 or ksvm I usually get accuracy values (i.e. the rate of correct predictions) of roughly 80% when doing a 10-fold cross validation.